# Python 3 Jupiter Notebook FORBIDDEN to be saved

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have Anaconda Navigator 1.8.4 with Python 3

I launched a Jupiter Notebook and tried to rename and save.

I have a "FORBIDDEN" message:

[W 17:34:45.280 NotebookApp] Terminals not available (error was DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.)
[I 17:34:45.625 NotebookApp] JupyterLab beta preview extension loaded from C:\Users\Toly_Novik\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 17:34:45.625 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Users\Toly_Novik\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[I 17:34:45.971 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\Toly_Novik
[I 17:34:45.971 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 17:34:45.971 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 17:34:45.971 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=76e4506e4a8b99e55400b3bcbb88ea1845477fb0599ec771
[I 17:34:45.972 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 17:34:45.984 NotebookApp]

Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
to login with a token:
http://localhost:8888/?token=76e4506e4a8b99e55400b3bcbb88ea1845477fb0599ec771
[I 17:34:46.716 NotebookApp] Accepting one-time-token-authenticated connection from ::1

I posted link into the browser as instructed. It opened a new Notebook but I have the same issue.

I have never seen these "tokens" used before.

Can you help in renaming and saving my work in a new notebook?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is in Firefox browser. Not sure why. Tried Chrome and Opera and I can rename and save my work without any messages about "tokens".

Someone may want to explore this further